# Change HC05 Available Baud Rate in Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth, serial-port, hc-05, com-port

I want to send data to Windows8.1 at 921600(bits/s) via hc05 module. But in the allowed rates of the module in Ports(COM & LPT) section of Device Manager for the COM port dedicated to hc05 bluetooth there is only up to 128000(bits/s).
[my  bluetooth com port setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUiJt.png) but for other Com port are as follows [Port Setting for VCPs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKoqA.png).

while in the module datasheet there is up to 1382400(bits/s). I changed the module transmission rate to 921600(bits/s) via at command, but I can not receive data for speeds above 115200(bits/s).
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify how you have this connected. Is it something like: `Arduino`<-com->`HC-05`<-bluetooth->`Windows bluetooth adaptor`<-com->`PuTTY (or some other client)`

Comment: I configured the module via real term and send the data via a stm32 microcontroller. To receive data in Windows 8.1, I connect to it via a dedicated port on Bluetooth. And I open this port either through special software written in C # or real term. But in C # software, an error is issued that baud rate does not exist more than 115200! And this is as true as the image I sent.